# nodejs jwt verify always fails

Tags: node.js, jwt

any idea why this test code always prints fail, I designed this code to figure out what is wrong with my authentication server for my school project and I wrote this to always verify but it never does

```
var refreshToken = jwt.sign({username: "test",}, "secret");
  const tokenARR = refreshToken.split('.');
  const signiture = tokenARR[2];
  jwt.verify(signiture, "secret", (err, user) => {
    if (err) { 
     console.log("fail");
     }
     else {
      console.log("TEST");
     }
    })
```

Comment: You're supposed to give `jwt.verify` the entire token, not just the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 3rd part of a JWT token is signature. But the `jwt.verify` function verify and decode the token at the same time.

So it must be `jwt.verify(refreshToken)` instead of `jwt.verify(signiture)`

Comment: Even if `jwt.verify` would only verify the signature, it would still need the complete JWT. The signature can only be verified against a token, the signature alone is meaningless.